# How to use int array as dictionary key C#

Tags: c#, dictionary

I was trying to make a dictionary but as a key it would use pair of integers.

```
public Dictionary<int[], car> listOfCells = new Dictionary<int[], car>();
```

but when i check if there is a value it always returns false

```
return listOfCells.ContainsKey(new int[] { x, y })
```

Comment: you should create dictionary in such a way `public Dictionary<int, int[]> listOfCells = new Dictionary<int, int[]>();` where key will be some unique identifier for the car

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Arrays are reference types. Thus, two arrays having the same contents have two different object identities and are not "equal".

If all your arrays have a constant number of elements (for example, if you use the array to store 2D coordinates), consider [using a value tuple](https://stackoverflow.com/q/53831071/87698) instead:

```
public Dictionary<(int, int), car> listOfCells = new Dictionary<(int, int), car>();
```